# Spring boot webservice to start and be discoverable when JBOSS EAP starts

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, jboss-eap-7

We need to create independent spring boot web services for our apps which runs in JBOSS EAP. Can we do the below if its possible.

1. Spring Boot is typically deployed as a runnable jar but our apps are EAR deployed. Can we bootstrap / launch the spring boot listener / controller when the EAR application starts)
2. Can we register the services on start to facilitate automated discoverability   of services (typically done with consul/ etcd/ zookeeper etc)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can generate a WAR instead of a JAR and deploy this. If this is not ok you can put the WAR in an EAR

Read the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

2. Yes. If you have a service registry in place you can use this with Spring Cloud.

Please read the documentation: 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/